# Existence of a basis for a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: 
V is a vector space over field F , W is a subspace of V. Is the next statement true or false?
"K is a basis for V, so exists a subset of K which is a basis for W".

What I did:

- K is a basis for V, therefore it is linearly independent.
- I pick a set L s.t. $L \subseteq K $ and $ L \subseteq W$ 
  (I'm allowed to assume that such set exists because $W \subseteq V$)
- Let $dim(W)=n, dim(V)=m, n \le m$.
- L is linearly independent because it's a subset of K which is also independent.
- $L \subseteq W \Rightarrow Sp(L) \subseteq W$
- Since $dimSp(L)=dimW$ then $Sp(L)=W$
- Therefore L is a linearly independent subset of K which is a basis for W.

Is this proof correct? I feel like I'm missing something here.

Thanks/

Comment: Think geometrically.  Let $V$ by $\mathbb{R}^3$, $W$ be a line or plane through the origin, $K$ a basis for $V$, and decide if the statement has to be true.

Answer (score 4):

Take a vector space $V$ of dimension $2$ over the field $F$ and a basis $\mathfrak{B}$ for it, so that $\lvert \mathfrak{B} \rvert = 2$.

Now can you think of a subspace $W$ of dimension $1$ which does not contain any element of $\mathfrak{B}$?

**Spoiler**

> If $\mathfrak{B} = \{ e_1, e_2 \}$, take $W = \langle e_1 - e_2 \rangle$.

So what is $L$ in this case in your second step? And what happens in the sixth step?

**Generalization**

> Let $V$ have dimension $n > 1$, and let $\mathfrak{B} = \{ e_1, \dots, e_n \}$ be a basis of $V$. Consider the subspace $W = \{ x_1 e_1 + \dots + x_n e_n : x_1 + \dots + x_n = 0 \}$. Then $\dim(W) = n-1$, and $\mathfrak{B} \cap W = \emptyset$.